# Как задать div до конца страницы

Tags: html, css

задача состоит в том, чтобы задать блок `div` до конца страницы, типо копирайт, как и на этой странице, однако если на странице текста мало, то этот блок не дотягивает до нижнего края. Даже если устанавливаю отрицательный `margin-bottom` все равно остается маленькая полосочка

```
.copyright {
    padding:5px;
    padding-top:20px;
    background-color:#e4e4e4;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin: auto;
    clear: both;
}

<div class="copyright">
    <span class="copyright-text">1</span><br />
    <span class="copyright-text">2</span><br />            
    <span class="copyright-text">3</span><br />   
    <span class="copyright-text">4</span><br />   
</div>
```

Comment: добавьте ваш код, с которым у вас проблемы, в вопрос - так всем будет проще

Comment: @lexxl добавил код

Comment: К сожалению не совсем ясно задачу, попробуйте привести пример на [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: @martdn да пример то не приведешь, в том то и проблема, надо сделать копирайт, чтобы он доставал конца страницы, но ниже не прокручивался, как на этом сайте, прокрутите вниз, и поймете что мне нужно.

Comment: Вам нужен каркас страницы с прижатым к низу футером.
Задаете блоку с текстом min - hight:100% , затем футер с помощью отрицательного марджина натягиваете на блок с текстом и делаете отступ в блоке паддингом. Да совсем забыл ,боди и хтмл нужно сделать также сделать высоту 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы это имели введу? [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/8ggvwxzh/)

```css
html{
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.content {
  width: 450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #666;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <p>Каждый веб-разработчик знает, что такое текст-«рыба». Текст этот, несмотря на название, не имеет никакого отношения к обитателям водоемов. Используется он веб-дизайнерами для вставки на интернет-страницы и демонстрации внешнего вида контента, просмотра шрифтов, абзацев, отступов и т.д. Так как цель применения такого текста исключительно демонстрационная, то и смысловую нагрузку ему нести совсем необязательно. Более того, нечитабельность текста сыграет на руку при оценке качества восприятия макета.
Самым известным «рыбным» текстом является знаменитый Lorem ipsum. Считается, что впервые его применили в книгопечатании еще в XVI веке. Своим появлением Lorem ipsum обязан древнеримскому философу Цицерону, ведь именно из его трактата «О пределах добра и зла» средневековый книгопечатник вырвал отдельные фразы и слова, получив текст-«рыбу», широко используемый и по сей день. Конечно, возникают некоторые вопросы, связанные с использованием Lorem ipsum на сайтах и проектах, ориентированных на кириллический контент – написание символов на латыни и на кириллице значительно различается.
И даже с языками, использующими латинский алфавит, могут возникнуть небольшие проблемы: в различных языках те или иные буквы встречаются с разной частотой, имеется разница в длине наиболее распространенных слов. Отсюда напрашивается вывод, что все же лучше использовать в качестве «рыбы» текст на том языке, который планируется использовать при запуске проекта. Сегодня существует несколько вариантов Lorem ipsum, кроме того, есть специальные генераторы, создающие собственные варианты текста на основе оригинального трактата, благодаря чему появляется возможность получить более длинный неповторяющийся набор слов.
</p>
    <div class="footer">
      footer
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ваш способ оказался наиболее близким, но мне прилось добавить еще один блок, с высотой равной `footer`, иначе `footer` залезает на `content`

Comment: а вообще, лучше использовать min-height наверно

Answer (score 1):

проверьте, равно ли нулю свойство padding у body и html.

Comment: проверил, не помогло

Comment: @max619, потому что не padding, а margin.

Answer (score 1):

Должно выглядеть так если я правильно вас понял:

```css
html, body, #wrapper{
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
}
#wrapper{
 width: 800px;
 margin: auto;
}
#main{
 min-height: 100%;
 margin-bottom: -100px;
 background: #9c0;
}
#footer{
 height: 100px;
 background: #f60;
}
#all{padding-bottom: 100px}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="main">
   <div id="all">текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст </div>   
  </div>
 <div id="footer"></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть такой [способ](https://jsfiddle.net/tjfuagmd/1/):

```css
    * {
      margin: 0;
    }
    html, body {
      height: 100%;
    }
    .page-wrap {
      min-height: 100%;
      /* equal to footer height */
      margin-bottom: -80px; 
    }
    .page-wrap:after {
      content: "";
      display: block;
    }
    .copyright, .page-wrap:after {
      height: 80px; 
    }
    .copyright {
      background: orange;
    }
```

```html
<div class="page-wrap">
  Content.
</div>

<div class="copyright">
  Copyright.
</div>
```

Comment: Ваш способ предполагает использование псевдокласса не по прямому назначению.....

Comment: Это нормально, главное что бы метод был кроссбраузерным. А этот один из таких.

В PostCSS всякие clearfix, sticky footer, блоки настраиваются одной строкой. А что получается в бандле, я даже не смотрю. Ну как, смотрю конечно, но только один раз.